# How to transfer text file with cURL in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I want to transfer a basic .txt file from one server to another server.

I'm stuck in how to handle the file on the destination server.

That's my code to send the textfile to the remote server:

```
// Create a cURL handle
$ch = curl_init();

// Create a CURLFile object
$cfile = new CURLFile('testfile.txt','text/plain');

// Assign POST data
$data = array("test_file" =>$cfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://example.com/upload.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

// Execute the handle
curl_exec($ch);
//close curl
curl_close ($ch);
```

That seems to work, the output of my `upload.php`file (with `print_r`) is as follows:

```
 [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => testfile.txt
        [type] => text/plain
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpGO8IhB
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 136
    )
```

Unfortunately I can't get it to work, that the testfile.txt lands at the remote server.

That was my last attempt, what didn't work out either:

```
if(isset($_FILES['test_file'])){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['testfile.txt']['test_file'], "uploads/");
}else{
    echo "error";
}
```

The only thing I know is, that the file seems to get to the server, but I'm doing something wrong. What do I have to do?

Comment: shouldn't move_uploaded_file($_FILES['testfile.txt']['test_file'], "uploads/");
 be move_uploaded_file($_FILES['testfile.txt']['tmp_name'], "uploads/");

Comment: @RobGudgeon That didn't work either. `echo  $_FILES['test_file'];` in my upload.php returns just "Array"..

Comment: var_dump($_FILES); to debug what you *do* get

Comment: @delboy1978uk That's the output `array(1) {
  ["test_file"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(23) "testfile.txt"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "text/plain"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpcqf9ta"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(136)
  }
}`

Comment: use $_FILES['test_file']['tmp_name']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `move_uploaded_file()` call should be:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['test_file']['tmp_name'], "uploads/yourfile.txt");
```

- Your files key is `test_file` and you are trying to access `test_file.txt` as a key.
- You need the `tmp_name` element not `test_file`.
- You need to provide a filename for the destination file not `uploads/` which is a directory. You can use the dynamic `$_FILES['test_file']['name']` but you must validate it.

Comment: That's the answer, yup!

Comment: Thank you very much MrCode and @delboy1978uk. 
I went crazy. In the end, not providing a filename for the destination file was my main problem. Have a good one!

Comment: By the way, thank you once again for the detailed explanation!